# How should I do to resize a partition taking free space from ntfs partition?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, ntfs, resize

I've the following partition scheme (I know this may cause vomit, nausea, etc. but we can discuss this in another question)

[image: partition scheme]

I must increase the size of the "/" partition (highlighted in the picture attached) which stores MySQL server and got empty while trying to import a big dump file.

Which steps should I follow so I could be able to increase the size of that partition? I have a ntfs partition which has 728Gb free

Comment: It may be easier to move the SQL server into its own partition, or another directory of an existing parition.

Comment: I should uninstall and reinstall lampp in advanced mode (I guess) and never did such before @SomeoneSomewhere

Comment: I don't know that you'd need to do that. Look up a guide on how to move /home onto its own partition after install - it's the same, just whichever directory stores the SQL DBs.

Comment: I meant. When I install lampp, it gets installed in the / partition automatically. I've never tried to install it into another partition nor tried to move or separate the MySQL server from it, I think it should "explode". And also, moving MySQL or its data into another partition is something I cannot afford. Will try resizing the partitions as you answered and will tell u how it went

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Make a backup. Messing around with partitions can cause data loss if something goes wrong, or make your system unable to boot**.

You'll need to boot off a LiveCD/USB, because you can't work on mounted partitions. Note that you won't be able to view mountpoints easily.

Select the NTFS partition, and shrink it from the left. Then expand the extended partition (`sda2`) to take up the freed space.

Then use the `resize/move` command to move each of `sda[6-10]` to the very right of your extended partition, probably while keeping the same size (unless you want to resize them).

Lastly, expand `sda5` (your `/` partition) into the freed-up space. Click apply, wait a while (**this will take several hours**), then reboot.

Comment: Hi again. I downloaded Gparted live, burnt the CD and booted. Then I resized the ntfs partition and clicked Apply. Borrowed from it100gb. Took me some 5' and it finished correctly. BUT: Now I cannot resize the SDA2 partition, it does not show me the free space from the unallocated space. Do I need another step/task ? Thanks again

Comment: Here is the screenshot took with my phone: http://i.imgur.com/NAdDffN.jpg

Comment: @Enrique you need to resize the partition so that the free space is on the left. I probably could have been clearer writing that.

Comment: I was able to shrink ntfs from left (took 4hs) and could add 150gb to /sda2 as you can see in the image. Now what should I do to increase sda5? thanks http://storage1.static.itmages.com/i/16/0503/h_1462271548_5567241_cd980687b3.jpeg

Comment: @Enrique Select the rightmost of each of the partitions in `sda2`, and move it to the right while keeping the same size. Repeat for each partition, except `sda5`

Comment: Awesome man! I have been wondering what you mean by moving until I understood that I could drag the partition itself to the right or left (depending where it were) and then got the point by reading in another post that you can increase the size of the partition only when you have unassigned space under(below) it and nothing else. Worked perfect. Thanks a lot for all your help !! Here it is http://storage9.static.itmages.com/i/16/0503/h_1462277461_8878291_835fd41c4a.jpeg